# Images in iPhone app appear in Simulator, but not when compiled to device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, compilation

I am learning iPhone development, and have built a simple app that has an image that changes to another image when you tap it.

If i build it to the simulator, it works fine, but if i build it to the device the images dont appear. i feel like they aren't being copied across. I have checked they have been named correctly and i have made sure i imported them to 'resources'

I dont think  it is a problem with the code because i added a thing to also make text appear when the image is tapped, and this works, so a button is still there doing something, it just doesn't have an image on it.

```
-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender { 
[fortuneCookieButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
label.hidden = NO; 
}

 -(IBAction)restoreImage:(id)sender { 
[fortuneCookieButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
label.hidden = YES; 
}
```

Comment: why don't you just post the code used to load the images?

Comment: Sorry :S that should have been an obvious thing do do

-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
 [fortuneCookieButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.jpg"]
       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  label.hidden = NO;
}

-(IBAction)restoreImage:(id)sender {
 [fortuneCookieButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.jpg"]
       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 label.hidden = YES;
}

Comment: you **must** use `.png` images only.

Answer (score 8):

Does the case (upper/lower) of all your file names match exactly for all letters?  Source code & project & Mac?

Comment: that is the most likely problem, and i'll have another, more thorough check. however, if this was the problem, why would the images appear in Simulator? (sorry if it's completely different and that's a dumb question)

Comment: Because the Simulator runs on the Mac's filesystem, which is case-preserving, case-insensitive, while the iOS device filesystem is case-preserving, case-sensitive.

Comment: The exact same problem happened to me. I had an image called IMG_0086.JPG but typed IMG_0086.jpg in my code. worked in the simulator but not on device.

Answer (score 5):

just to share with you, I had this same problem and I found out the solution: I was using lower case in the file name and upper case in code. The thing is on Simulator there was no problem because Mac file system is case-insensitive but in the iPad it didn't work because iOS file system is case sensitive.  ;-)

Comment: dude! thank you so much!! This was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. Bizarrely the image had been working in the past, then just stopped appearing on the device one day.

It was a PNG.

I opened it in GIMP and saved it again. Then it went back to working again. No idea why.

Crazy.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, that was because the file was previously a *jpg, **renamed** (not saved) in png. The simulator supported it, but not the real device.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case with only PNG images or also for JPG & other format you're having same issue. If it's only for PNG image, then it might be possible they're not being compressed. Try the following way.

Select your project target & go into its info. Here go into the build tab. In the configuration select "All Configurations" from Configuration section. Now, write "COMPRESS_PNG_FILES' in the search bar. And see the status of the check-box. IF it's unchecked, then make it checked & it will work. But if it's already checked, then there should be other reason in your project.

In the later case, I would request you to create a new dummy project & check by adding 2-3 images whether it's coming or not.

Comment: the images are jpegs, but in an unrelated incident, the App's icon is a png and that doesn't appear. ill try your compress idea for that

Answer (score 0):

Clear caches delete the previous build and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem, and it was caused by a different reason: my project has image files with the same name! Since my app has many images, I inadvertently included images with the same name. Simulator is more tolerant and show the images just fine; however, when built on device, neither of the images of the same name were copied to the build directory. Obviously xcode is more picky for device: since all images go to the same directory, the file names must be different. When there are files with the same name, xcode refuses to copy any of them since it doesn't know which one to pick.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my case, the issues is to do with the UILabel above the UIImageView that shows the image. When I change the type of UILabel to AttributedText (In Property Inspector), my real devices cannot load the image. When I change it back to Plain, it works now. I use XCode 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

on top of all suggestions - it wasn't work for me until I restarted the device